# How to convert Delphi dates in SQL Server into DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: sql-server, delphi

In my SQL Server database dates are stored in Delphi format (as integers). For example 43696 represents date 19.08.2019. I transform it into DD.MM.YYYY format using:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,delphidate-2),104)
```

(Actually here I have two conversions: first conversion of INTEGER into DATETIME format, then conversion of DATETIME into formatted VARCHAR).

Is there any easier (more convenient) means to do that?

Comment: "*dates are stored in Delphi format (as integers)*" - why? SQLServer has a native [`date` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that would be more appropriate, and is actually smaller to store (3 bytes) than an integer (4 bytes)

Comment: why do you want to convert the date to a `string`. You should keep it as `datetime`

Comment: Also, Delphi dates have a different epoch than SQLServer dates, so I don't think `delphidate-2` will suffice to convert a Delphi date to an SQL date

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why it is stored in that format!? I don't know. Application that stores data into database is written in Delphi and someone decided that this is fine with him to store dates as integers. So, that's how it is. I just took over the database.

Comment: @Squirrel I need to create report with data in DD.MM.YYYY (date only) format, if I leave DATETIME format (w/o outer conversion into VARCHAR) then I get 19.08.2019 00:00:00 in report.

Comment: @sbrbot Delphi dates are expressed as the # of days since Dec 30 1899. To get a valid SQL date from a Delphi date, simply add the Delphi date to that epoch, ie `DATEADD(day, delphidate, '1899-12-30')`. For easy reuse, consider adding a calculated `date` field to your table to invoke that function

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME,delphidate-2)` and `DATEADD(DAY,delphidate,'1899-12-30')` give the same result

Comment: @sbrbot From the documentation: _The return value data type for this method (`DATEADD`) is dynamic. The return type depends on the argument supplied for `date` (third parameter). If the value for date is a string literal date, DATEADD returns a datetime value. If another valid input data type is supplied for date, DATEADD returns the same data type._.  If you want a `date` result fata type, try with the following statement: `SELECT DATEADD(day, delphidate, DATEFROMPARTS(1899, 12, 30))`.

Comment: @sbrbot using `DATEADD` is more explicit and easier to understand than using magic numbers. I don't see how subtracting 2 days from a Delphi date converts it to an SQL date, as the difference between the epochs of the respective types is WAY more than 2 days

Comment: @RemyLebeau `CONVERT(datetime,0)` returns `1900-01-01`, in this case _epoch_ and lower bound of the range are not the same.

Comment: @BrakNicku OK, thanks

Comment: @Zhorov unfortunately my SQL Server is 2008R2 - Kilimanjaro (v10.50) and says "DATEFROMPARTS is not a recognized built-in function name" :-(

Answer (score -1):

you have to pass datedelphi as parameters query of type datetime
and then use your conversion to  set time to 00:00:00

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME, :delphidate-2),104)
```